# Jquery Validation From Another Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I am using the `http://jqueryvalidation.org/` to validate my forms and by default this is called when the form gets submitted. I am wanting to start the validation when the function I have wrapped it into is called.

So basically, I have this for the validation:

```
function ticketCreateSubmit()
{
   $("#ticketForm").validate({
      ...
   });
}
```

And then this is getting called by: `ticketCreateSubmit();` in my payments page. The form does have the id of `ticketForm`. The function does get called, but the validation does not take action?

I searched the validation website and I found that if I put `onsubmit: false,` it doesn't process it on form submit, but that still didn't get the validation to run when the function is being called?

How would I go about this?

Just so everyone understands, I'm only needing to call the VALIDATION so it runs from the external script. I'm not needing to do anything else. Just execute the validation.

Comment: `$("#ticketForm").validate()` attaches a validator to the form. It's not executing the validation.

Comment: I've figured that much out....... I'm asking what I can do to execute the validation. I'm not able to find anything on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting `onsubmit="ticketCreateSubmit();return false"` on the form submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var form = $("#ticketForm")
form.validate({
      ...
});

function ticketCreateSubmit()
{
  form.valid() 
}
```